# Mongoose: Query in an array for values from another array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like:

```
const Combined = new Schema({
    done: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'orders' }], 
    notDone: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'orders' }],
    extraInfo: { type: {} }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });
```

When I was going for all `Orders` that have an `order._id` either in `done` or `notDone` I was going:

```
const query = {
    $or: [
        { done: { $all: [order._id] } },
        { notDone: { $all: [order._id] } }
    ],
    $populate: ['done', 'notDone']
}
```

Now I have a list of `orders._id`'s

How do I get all `Combined` where `done` or `notDone` contains `ANY` of `_id`'s from the `orders._id` list inside?